# pip install old version with optional dependencies

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Is there a way to install an old version of a package with optional dependencies?

For example, I can `pip install pandas[xml]` that would install the current pandas version with the xml extra dependencies.

Nonetheless, when I do `pip install pandas==1.4.4[xml]`, the following error appears: `ERROR: Extras after version '==1.4.4[xml]'.` From the [archived documentation of pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.4/getting_started/install.html#xml) the [xml] extra dependencies already existed in version 1.4.4.

Answer (score -1):

first you need to install the specific version of the package using pip:

```
pip install pandas==1.4.4
```

after install the optional dependencies separately:

```
pip install pandas[xml]==1.4.4
```

Comment: No need to install `pip install pandas==1.4.4` separately, `pip install "pandas[xml]==1.4.4"` works just fine alone.